# Tire not seeing singular/plural?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

From everything I have read this should work. I'm re-indexing after each change.

My category names are stored as plural, e.g. "books", "movies" or "tapes". In rails terms this is the same as `@resource.category.name`

It works if i search `books` but does not work if i search `book`. I'm trying to make it so you can search either singular or plural and find a result for the category

```
  # Tire

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  mapping do
    indexes :url
    indexes :title,       :boost => 3
    indexes :description, :boost => 2
    indexes :categories do
      indexes :name, analyzer: 'snowball', :boost => 1.5, store: 'true'
    end
    indexes :user do
      indexes :username, analyzer: 'keyword'
    end
  end  

  def self.elasticsearch(params)
    tire.search(
        :load => { :include => [:tags] }, 
        :page => params[:page], 
        :per_page => 20) do
      query { string params[:e], default_operator: "OR" } # if params[:e].present?
    end
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    to_json( include: { user: { only: [:username] }, 
                    category: { only: [:name] } } )
  end
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of queries that you are running? Are you searching only within the categories field or you are not specifying the field in your queries? If the latter is the case, your queries are executed against the _all field. The _all field is using standard analyzer by default, which doesn't stem plurals.

Comment: Igor, I think your commment is valuable enough to make it an answer :), so @Tallboy can accept it.

Comment: Yes that would be helpful. I'm also not 100% sure what you mean, maybe an example would help :/ sorry, i really have read the documentation I am very confused

Comment: imotov, I'm really sorry I can't answer that more fully. All of what I am trying to do is above, i suppose what youre referring to is `query { string params[:e], default_operator: "OR" } `. All that is doing is taking &e=Hello%20World from the URL and passing that to elasticsearch. I'm not doing any other 'special' things other than what's in my code there

Comment: This is what it looks like when I log it. `{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"hello-world","default_operator":"OR"}},"size":20}`